# How to log both of same letters if one is guessed

Tags: javascript, arrays

My Hangman game is working well but i have a problem: ...............................................................................................................................................................
When the word to guess has two of the same letters and I guess one,both of them are supposed to log but it only logs one of the two.

```
function playgame(yourword) {

    //yourword array
    /*********************/
    let word = yourword.toUpperCase();
    let letters = word.split("");
    var answerArray = [letters[0]];
    for (var i = 1; i < letters.length; i++) {
        answerArray[i] = "_";
    }
    let answer = answerArray.join();

    //hangman array
    /*********************/
    let hgm = ["H", "A", "N", "G", "M", "A", "N"];
    let hgArray = [hgm[0]];
    for (var i = 1; i < hgm.length; i++) {
        hgArray[i] = "_";
    }
    //loop
    let remainingLetters = word.length;
    let remainingLetter = hgm.length;
    while (remainingLetters > 0 & remainingLetter > 0) {

        //show the array
        console.log(answerArray.join(" ").toUpperCase());
        console.log(hgArray.join(",").toUpperCase());

        let guess = prompt("guess a letter").toUpperCase();
        //add a letter if guessed correctly
        for (var i = 0; i < letters.length; i++) {
            if (word[i] === guess) {
                answerArray[i] = guess;
                remainingLetters--;
            }
            //add a letter to the hangman string if guessed incorrecty 
            //MY PROBLEM IS HERE

            for (var h = 0; h < hgm.length; h++) {
                if (word[h] !== guess) {
                    remainingLetter--;
                }

                //TO HERE

            }

        }
        console.log(answerArray.join(" ").toUpperCase());
        console.log(hgArray.join(",").toUpperCase());
        if (remainingLetters === 0) {
            console.log("you win");
        } else if (remainingLetters !== 0) {
            console.log("you lose");
        }
    }
}
```

Example of what should happen

```
playgame('hello')

***********************
H_ _ _ _
//If i guess l if should do

H_  l l _ 

//NOT
H_  l _ _
```

Please help out

Answer (score 0):

Check this code, Your code was almost correct. I did only few changes. I Check it is working fine.

```
function playgame(yourword) {
//yourword array
/*********************/
let word = yourword.toUpperCase();
let letters = word.split("");
var answerArray = [letters[0]];
for (var i = 1; i < letters.length; i++) {
    answerArray[i] = "_";
}
let answer = answerArray.join();

//hangman array
/*********************/
let hgm = ["H", "A", "N", "G", "M", "A", "N"];
let hgArray = [hgm[0]];
for (var i = 1; i < hgm.length; i++) {
    hgArray[i] = "_";
}
//loop
let remainingLetters = word.length - 1;  // First letter is visible by default
let remainingLetter = hgm.length;
while (remainingLetters > 0 && remainingLetter > 0) {

    //show the array
    console.log(answerArray.join(" ").toUpperCase());
    console.log(hgArray.join(",").toUpperCase());

    let guess = prompt("guess a letter").toUpperCase();
    //add a letter if guessed correctly
    for (var i = 0; i < letters.length; i++) {
    if (word[i] === guess) {
        answerArray[i] = guess;
        remainingLetters--;
    }
    //add a letter to the hangman string if guessed incorrecty 
    //MY PROBLEM IS HERE

    if (word.indexOf(guess) === -1) {
        remainingLetter--;
    }

}
console.log(answerArray.join(" ").toUpperCase());
console.log(hgArray.join(",").toUpperCase());
if (remainingLetters === 0) {
    console.log("you win");
} else if (remainingLetters !== 0) {
    console.log("you lose");
}
  }
  }

  playgame('Hello');
```